# Removing items from listbox using backgroundworker

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, backgroundworker

I want to delete all the items of a listbox that does NOT contain "mysite" and here's my code that works fine without **backgroundworker**.

Do Work Event:

```
Dim relevantSite As Integer = 0
Do Until relevantSite = lstLinks.Items.Count
    If lstLinks.Items.Item(relevantSite).ToString.Contains("mysite") Then
        relevantSite += 1
    Else
        bgWorker.ReportProgress(relevantSite)
    End If
Loop
```

ProgressChanged Event:

```
lstLinks.Items.RemoveAt(CInt(e.ProgressPercentage))
```

What it does is, it removes alot of items, sometimes all items. I know I'm making some terrible mistake with `e` and `reportProgress` thing.

Please explain them to me, I searched various sites but could not understand it...

Comment: How many of your items contain the string "mysite". if there are many, then your code is working correctly. please advise. also note the first argument of ReportProgress is an indication of the progress of an operation. The second argument, UserState, is the value you should be using to pass the index.

Comment: Why are you using background worker? I can't see it adding any value here as the progress changed event is much heavier than the DoWork. Is there additional processing in it you are not showing? Can't you just filter the sites in the initial load?

Comment: You hope that the ProgressChanged event handler runs when you call ReportProgress.  It doesn't, it runs later.  Indeed completely messing up the listview.  Do not use a worker for code like this.

Comment: See, even Hans agrees with me.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than directly changing the items in the list you should create a new list in your background worker.  This way you can add remove items from the list and return it to the UI once all the processing is completed and rebind the drop down.

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting the code to act as if it is synchronized. But multi-threading does not work that way.

Your code in do work will be processing the next record before report progress has completed. In other words the loop will not pause and wait for report progress to complete. This is a problem because when you call out to remove a item from the list, you reuse the index assuming the item is gone. After a few removals, the index passed in will not indicate the correct item. If you were to use an identifier rather than an index it would work. But the whole thing seems wrong to me since you are not doing any heavy lifting in the do work method.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to delete all the items of a listbox that does NOT contain
>   "mysite"

Walk the ListBox **backwards** and delete the offending items as you go.  Wrap the process in BeginUpdate() and EndUpdate() so the ListBox only refreshes once when you're all done:

```
    lstLinks.BeginUpdate()
    Dim NumItems As Integer = lstLinks.Items.Count - 1
    For i As Integer = NumItems To 0 Step -1
        If Not lstLinks.Items(i).ToString.Contains("mysite") Then
            lstLinks.Items.RemoveAt(i)
        End If
    Next
    lstLinks.EndUpdate()
    lstLinks.Refresh()
```